# how to add the value of 3 arrays into one array

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays meat,veg and sauce,
I was wondering how to add their values to a new array called food.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [concat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
var food = meat.concat(veg,sauce);
```

Comment: Just call concat on one of the arrays with the other arrays as arguments. It will return the merged array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object:

```
var food = {
    meat: meat,
    veg: veg,
    sauce: sauce
};
```

Then you can access the arrays with `food.meat`, `food.veg` and `food.sauce`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat()`:

```
var meat = ["m","e","a","t"];
var veg = ["v","e","g"];
var sauce = ["s","a","u","c","e"];

var food = meat.concat(veg, sauce);
alert(food);
```

I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you should use the concat function to return a copy of the combined arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat